# Safety issue of running exe on a server

Tags: python, attacks, safety

I'm pretty new to server-side stuff. The difficult situation is that we want to allow an application installed on the server to run python on the server, but the *application server installation guide* said that "running EXE files creates a vulnerability that can be exploited by attackers,", so I'm wondering how risky that is and is there a way for us to reduce the risks?

I'm currently not very sure if the server is a shared server or a VPS. I guess it's probably shared.

Thank you very much! And I'm looking forward to hearing from you!

Comment: contact support application provider and inform the issue , may be they have security patches for those issues

Comment: Thanks Aravinda, I'll ask their support at the same time! Thank you!

Comment: The risk is not letting installed application run, the risk is letting a user run anything he want on the server. As some server can be deployed as a terminal server.

Comment: Hi, @yagmoth555 thank you for the feedback! I think for this application, we indeed need to specify a user to impersonate the custom program. If the risk is mainly from the user, what if we use the virtual service account, would it greatly reduce the risk though?